# node.js export variables across files

Tags: node.js, express, chef-infra, middleware

I'm relatively new to web development, brand new to node.js.

I'm trying to use express to make a site that updates an api with the [chef-node api](https://github.com/sgentle/chef-node) client, using [this tutorial](http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/)

If I create a stand alone node.js app, it works as expected, and the value 'bacon' is set to 'good'

app1.js

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    chef = require('chef'),
    key = fs.readFileSync('/Users/foo.pem'),
    chef_client = chef.createClient('foo', key, 'https://chef.example.com/organizations/dev');

var mybreakfast = { "id":"food","bacon":"good"}
chef_client.put('/data/breakfast/food', mybreakfast,  function(err,res,body) {
  if (err) { return console.log(err); }
  console.log(body)
});
```

[Full code is here](https://gist.github.com/spuder/1601ab806ec6ef42d34c).
The app basically looks like this:
app.js

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    chef = require('chef'),
    key = fs.readFileSync('/Users/foo.pem'),
    chef_client = chef.createClient('foo', key, 'https://chef.example.com/organizations/dev');
 ...
 //tutorial says this isn't ideal, but it is quickest way to get working
 app.use(function(req,res,next){
     req.client = chef_client;
     next();
 });
```

routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/databags', function(req, res) {
  req.client.get('/data/breakfast/food',  function(err,res,body) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    console.log("Found breakfast")
    console.log(body)
    bag_data = body; //TODO: Global variable is bad and you should feel bad, how do I use correct variable?
  });
  res.render('databags.jade', { title: 'Databags', somedata: bag_data });
});

router.post('/databags', function(req, res) {
  var mybreakfast = { "id":"food","bacon":"good"}
  req.client.put('/data/breakfast/food', mybreakfast,  function(err,res,body) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    console.log(body)
  });

});
```

vies/databags.jade

```
html
  body
    form(action='/databags', id='derp', method='POST')
      each value, key in somedata
        label #{key}  
        input(type='text',name="#{key}", value="#{value}")
        br
        br
      input(type='submit', value='Submit', form='derp')
```

When I press the submit button in /databags, I get a 301 and no data is uploaded.

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>openresty/1.7.10.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I suspect the problem has to do with the fact that I'm adding client to every request.

```
 //tutorial says this isn't ideal, but it is quickest way to get working
 app.use(function(req,res,next){
     req.client = chef_client;
     next();
 });
```

What is the proper way to make the chef_client variable in app.js available in routes/index.js?

If that is the correct way to do this, then what could be making the app work by itself, but not when used with the express framework?

Since this is my first node.js / express site, any other suggestions to get this app working would be very appreciated.

**Update**

Solution has been found, working code snippet available here: https://gist.github.com/spuder/1e39868b6a9a0c3cdb13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `route_index.js` is your `routes/index.js` then your problem is that you're not actually exporting anything from it. When you `require('routes/index')` you're going to get back whatever you set `module.exports` to to in that file.

That means your `routes/index.js` file should end with:

```
module.exports = router;
```

To address your question regarding how to share `chef_client` without a global, you can return a factory from `routes/index.js` that returns an instantiated router using the parameters you pass to it. That would look something like this:

**routes/chef.js**

```
function addChefRoutes(router, chefClient) {
  router.get('databags', function(res,req){
    // ...
  }
});

module.exports = addChefRoutes;
```

**app.js**

```
var chefClient = chef.createClient('foo', key, 'https://chef.example.com/organizations/dev');
var addChefRoutes = require('./routes/chef');
var router = express.Router();

addChefRoutes(router, chefClient);
```

Comment: Thank you, the 301 error was caused by not having https in url. For posterity, this code works https://gist.github.com/spuder/1e39868b6a9a0c3cdb13